# How to find out address of recursive dns server I am using?

Tags: linux, dns

I would like to find out address of recursive DNS server which gives me dns replies. Something like `tracepath example.com` to look for which dns servers ip addresses my request was forwarded to. I found `dig +trace example.com` but it is more about DNS resolving path which this recursive DNS server takes.

I know about `resolvectl status` where systemd's resolved shows which DNS server i'm actually using instead of 127.0.0.53:53. This point me to my router which also have its DNS server point to another router in my lan or to actual ISP DNS server which gave me answer when i used dig/nslookup as far as i understand.

The usual way is to look in my modem connection statistics for dns ip that gave me my isp dhcp server. But I am looking for a better way, i.e. simple command line tool.

---

After some more search I stumbled upon https://www.dnsleaktest.com and this is practically  functionality i'm looking for. But i don't really care if my ISP will proxy requests, I would like to just know how to get the ip of recursive DNS server without depending on some website api.

Answer (score 0):

#### I would like to just know how to get the ip of recursive DNS server

If you are asking what DNS server has the exact answer to the request then it is not possible to find out.

There is a nice answer on http://serverfault.com which explains why:

> > I want to know what exact server in the end had the answer. Is that possible?
>
> This is not achievable. You will not find the *specific* authoritative
> server that was consulted named anywhere in the payload of a DNS
> reply. There are CHAOS queries that exist for the purpose of
> identifying the specific *recursive* server that replied to you, but
> no such equivalent for extracting the name of the exact authoritative
> server that a recursor obtained the data from.
>
> The StackOverflow Q&A that Phillip linked to provides instructions for
> how to identify the list of `NS` records that were present in the
> authority section of a recursive DNS response. This is the full list
> of servers though, not the *specific* server. Even were that
> sufficient for your uses, this information is considered optional by
> the DNS standards and it is increasingly rare to see it in recursive
> responses in order to reduce the payload size of internally sourced
> reflection attacks.
>
> If you know the name of the zone, you can request the full list of
> `NS` records via an explicit request for them. This requires knowing
> that you are at the apex of the zone; a request for `example.com` NS
> records will return the desired response but `www.example.com` will
> not, unless `www` was delegated to another set of servers. In this
> case, you have no choice but to work backwards iteratively until you
> discover the apex of the zone.
>
> Long story short, there is no reliable short path (i.e. single query)
> to getting information about *all* upstream authority from a recursive
> server, and there is **no** way to learn the specific authoritative
> server that responded to a query without also controlling the
> authoritative server and creating unique data on each server. (if you
> do this, please create a unique zone for that purpose so that it does
> not interfere with your more sensitive production zone transfers)

Source: [Find out which DNS server answered your query](https://serverfault.com/a/858001/251339), answer by [Andrew B](https://serverfault.com/users/152073/andrew-b)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109922/discussion-on-answer-by-davidpostill-how-to-find-out-address-of-recursive-dns-se).